# Kubuntu 14.04 hangs at startup after installing fglrx

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, xorg, fglrx

After installing the new AMD Catalyst beta driver (14.6), my system hangs at the boot screen, however I am able to access the TTY terminals.

I installed fglrx as follows:

1. Downloaded the drivers from AMD's official site
2. Generated the .deb packages using the --buildpkg option
3. Installed the generated packages
4. Ran `sudo amdconfig --initial`

I have also tried deleting and modifying the xorg.conf file, but for some reason it gets overwritten on every reboot.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue? I am very frustrated with this problem and would greatly appreciate any help.

**I do not want to use the open source drivers.** I am trying to install and run the proprietary AMD driver, nothing else.

Comment: You should report bugs in the Catalyst beta driver directly to AMD. Their bugtracker is at http://ati.cchtml.com/ What card are you using?

Answer (score 0):

AMD recently removed support for some graphics cards from there driver. Find out whether you are affected.

First remove the installed driver:

> sudo apt-get remove fglrx fglrx-updates

Alternatively you can use the `*.run` file you downloaded from AMD website to remove the driver:

> sudo bash *.run --uninstall

Clear fglrx apt cache:

`sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/*fglrx*`

If you need to switch to the Ubuntu's default open source driver, execute:

> sudo apt-get install xf86-video-ati

Or install the Ubuntu verified proprietary driver:

> sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates

Comment: I am not affected, my graphics card is fairly new (AMD Radeon HD 7560D).

Answer (score 0):

There's also instructions on the AMD website about removing the drivers entirely and revertiing to the xorg open source drivers:

```
sudo aticonfig --uninstall
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-x86.x86_64.run --uninstall 
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.removed
```

The second and third commands may not run in your system, depending upon how the drivers were installed.  The fifth command may need to be changed to restore a prior version of the xorg.conf file - you should examine the contents of the /etc/X11 directory to determine if you need an earlier version that the fglrc drivers installed.

Comment: I have already removed the driver multiple times and everything went back to normal. However, I do not want to use the open source drivers.

Comment: I've got a couple of computers with the same issue - I'd *like* to use the AMD drivers because there is a heat buildup issue with the laptops my wife uses, however the AMD drivers are not able to detect and operate the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

fglrx is not supported on 14.04.2 and above. Which is what you have.

So, the solution is:

1. Remove fglrx, radeon and other drivers.
2. install the vesa driver.
3. Downgrade to kernel and X.org stack on 3.13 kernel
4. Now install fglrx
5. Now boot into the 3.13 series kernel you just installed fglrx to.

Commands:

```
sudo aptitude purge fglrx 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty linux-generic-lts-trusty
```

Now reboot to 3.13 series kernel. Reboot, during startup go to Other Ubuntu Versions, there choose the kernel.
Now the default packaged fglrx drivers will install.

```
sudo aptitude install fglrx-updates
```

Now reboot. fglrx should now work.